# Can't build OpenCV3.1 for Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I downloaded opencv and opencv contrib files, following the tutorial here: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/

I want to install OpenCV3 for Python2.7 in a Conda environment called obj_recog. My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.
I then tried running the Cmake with different options, finally settling on this:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON \
-D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_GTK=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D WITH_CUDA=ON \
-D CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/cuda-8.0 -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.1.0/modules \
-D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/anaconda3/envs/obj_recog/bin/python \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_CUBLAS=ON ..
```

Here is the output I get:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_GTK=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D WITH_CUDA=ON -D CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/cuda-8.0 -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.1.0/modules -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/anaconda3/envs/obj_recog/bin/python -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_CUBLAS=ON ..
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detected version of GNU GCC: 54 (504)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_W
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_W - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WALL
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WALL - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WALL
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WALL - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_ADDRESS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_ADDRESS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_ADDRESS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_ADDRESS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WFORMAT
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WFORMAT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WINIT_SELF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WINIT_SELF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WINIT_SELF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WINIT_SELF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WPOINTER_ARITH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WPOINTER_ARITH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WPOINTER_ARITH
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WPOINTER_ARITH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSIGN_PROMO - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_NARROWING
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_NARROWING - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_NARROWING
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_NARROWING - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_LONG_LONG
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_LONG_LONG - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_LONG_LONG
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_LONG_LONG - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_PTHREAD - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_PTHREAD - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE2
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE2
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_AVX
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_AVX - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_AVX
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_AVX - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE3
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE3
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_SSSE3
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_SSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_SSSE3
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_SSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_SSE4_1
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_SSE4_1 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_SSE4_1
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_SSE4_1 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_SSE4_2
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_SSE4_2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_SSE4_2
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_SSE4_2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN - Failed
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- Found ZLIB: /home/geoff/anaconda3/envs/obj_recog/lib/libz.so (found suitable version "1.2.8", minimum required is "1.2.3") 
-- Found TIFF: /home/geoff/anaconda3/envs/obj_recog/lib/libtiff.so (found version "4.0.6") 
-- Found JPEG: /home/geoff/anaconda3/envs/obj_recog/lib/libjpeg.so  
-- Found WebP: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so  
-- Found Jasper: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (found version "1.900.1") 
-- Found ZLIB: /home/geoff/anaconda3/envs/obj_recog/lib/libz.so (found version "1.2.8") 
-- Found PNG: /home/geoff/anaconda3/envs/obj_recog/lib/libpng.so (found version "1.6.22") 
-- Looking for /home/geoff/anaconda3/envs/obj_recog/include/libpng/png.h
-- Looking for /home/geoff/anaconda3/envs/obj_recog/include/libpng/png.h - not found
-- Looking for semaphore.h
-- Looking for semaphore.h - found
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SWITCH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SWITCH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_PARENTHESES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_PARENTHESES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ARRAY_BOUNDS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ARRAY_BOUNDS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_EXTRA
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_EXTRA - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-base-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-video-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-video-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-app-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-riff-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-base-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-video-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-video-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-app-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-riff-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'libdc1394-2'
--   Found libdc1394-2, version 2.2.4
-- Checking for module 'libv4l1'
--   Found libv4l1, version 1.10.0
-- Checking for module 'libv4l2'
--   Found libv4l2, version 1.10.0
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
-- Checking for module 'libavcodec'
--   Found libavcodec, version 57.64.101
-- Checking for module 'libavformat'
--   Found libavformat, version 57.56.100
-- Checking for module 'libavutil'
--   Found libavutil, version 55.34.100
-- Checking for module 'libswscale'
--   Found libswscale, version 4.2.100
-- Checking for module 'libavresample'
--   No package 'libavresample' found
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h - found
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h - not found
-- Checking for module 'libgphoto2'
--   No package 'libgphoto2' found
-- Checking for module 'tbb'
--   Found tbb, version 4.4~20151115
-- ICV: Removing previous unpacked package: /home/geoff/opencv-3.1.0/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack
-- ICV: Unpacking ippicv_linux_20151201.tgz to /home/geoff/opencv-3.1.0/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack...
-- ICV: Package successfully downloaded
-- found IPP (ICV version): 9.0.1 [9.0.1]
-- at: /home/geoff/opencv-3.1.0/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx
-- CUDA detected: 8.0
-- CUDA NVCC target flags: -gencode;arch=compute_20,code=sm_20;-gencode;arch=compute_20,code=sm_21;-gencode;arch=compute_30,code=sm_30;-gencode;arch=compute_35,code=sm_35;-gencode;arch=compute_30,code=compute_30
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- To enable PlantUML support, set PLANTUML_JAR environment variable or pass -DPLANTUML_JAR=<filepath> option to cmake
-- Found PythonInterp: /home/geoff/anaconda3/envs/obj_recog/bin/python (found suitable version "2.7.12", minimum required is "2.7")
```

When I execute `make j-4` as in the tutorial, the make then breaks around 40%.

I also tried installing by using `conda install opencv`, but then I can't read `.avi` videos or images, getting the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvShowImage, file /root/mc-x64-2.7/conda-bld/opencv-3_1482256854890/work/opencv-3.1.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 545
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "find_game.py", line 24, in <module>
   cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.error: /root/mc-x64-2.7/conda-bld/opencv-3_1482256854890/work/opencv-3.1.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:545: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvShowImage
```

I checked and `libgtk2-0-dev` is correctly installed.

Before building OpenCV by hand, I also compiled and reinstalled ffmpeg and gstreamer.

During the `make`, I get this error:

```
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsoxr.so.0: undefined reference to `GOMP_parallel@GOMP_4.0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
samples/opengl/CMakeFiles/example_opengl_opengl_interop.dir/build.make:107: recipe for target 'bin/opengl-example-opengl_interop' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/opengl-example-opengl_interop] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:31556: recipe for target 'samples/opengl/CMakeFiles/example_opengl_opengl_interop.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [samples/opengl/CMakeFiles/example_opengl_opengl_interop.dir/all] Error 2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

https://realpython.com/blog/python/face-detection-in-python-using-a-webcam/

If you follow this link and  you can try running this code

```
git clone https://github.com/shantnu/Webcam-Face-Detect.git
cd  cd Webcam-Face-Detect/
sudo python webcam_cv3.py haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml
```

typing the sudo python did the trick for me , i was getting errors when using just python.So try running with sudo.

Comment: But then, it won't use a conda/virtual env, it will only work with the system python version.

Answer (score 0):

This error is nothing to do with  libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config. Probably both are installed, but you still get the same error everytime you try to run make.

This often happen when you have tried to install opencv from different sources (for exemple opencv-python, official python, etc). Try to uninstall all opencv related packages (specially if they were not the official one), and start over. I even had to re-install ubuntu once.

The instructions from pyimagesearch work well.